# User defined activation function in CNTK

Tags: python, cntk

Is there way to provide user defined activation function for layers in CNTK (Python API) instead of only primitive ones like tanh, relu etc.?
Something like this

```
def f(x):
    return x * x
LSTM(number_of_cells, activation=f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you wrote should work as is.

This tutorial might be useful to you: 
https://www.cntk.ai/Tutorials/CVPR2017/CVPR_2017_Tutorial_final.pdf

Also, CNTK has a number of tutorials and manuals: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Tutorials
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Manual

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote should work, you can use any of the CNTK expression to compose a more complex activation function.